# PySide2 crashes while accessing QObject::property()

Tags: python, qt, pyside2, qobject, qmetaobject

So I am not sure this is a bug or something but I have spent quite sometime to figure this out but couldn't. The problem happens when accessing calling `QObject::property()` function.
Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
import sys

from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, QCoreApplication, QObject, Slot
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine, QQmlContext



class MyItem(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyItem, self).__init__()
        self.name = "John"
        self.age = 22

    @QtCore.Property(QtCore.QObject, constant=True)
    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    @QtCore.Property(QtCore.QObject, constant=True)
    def getAge(self):
        return self.age

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    provider = MyModelProvider()
    item = MyItem()
    print(item.property("getName")) # the program crashes here
    QApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)
    QCoreApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps)

    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty('provider', provider)
    engine.load('qml/main.qml')
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The program always crashes with the following output:

```
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fails because the variable that returns `getName` is not a `QObject` but a `str`, similarly to `getAge` that returns an `int`, so the solution is to set the correct signature

```py
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import Property, QObject, QCoreApplication


class MyItem(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyItem, self).__init__(parent)
        self.name = "John"
        self.age = 22

    @Property(str, constant=True)
    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    @Property(int, constant=True)
    def getAge(self):
        return self.age


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    item = MyItem()
    print(item.property("getName"))
    print(item.property("getAge"))
```

Output:

```
John
22
```